# How to adjust the position and size of image view elements to take advantage of additional screen space on larger devices?

Tags: java, android

Image view elements stay the same regardless of device size. So while is optimized for a smaller screen like a Nexus 6, the orientation or spacing of the various buttons and image views are not appropriate on a tablet device like the Nexus 7.

Is this because the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes are defined specifically?

As for the aspect ratio, answers suggestions on certain questions have suggested that `android:scaleType=fitXY` be used have not yielded any effective results.

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/ring"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ring"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Do image view elements have to be both resized and scaled?

Somewhat similar questions:

[Layout screwed up on bigger screen sizes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918271/layout-screwed-up-on-bigger-screen-sizes-not-taking-advantage-of-the-extra-spac)

[How to evaluate view size to keep same proportion in all devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424627/android-how-to-evaluate-view-size-to-keep-same-proportion-in-all-devices)

Comment: what is your problem actually, why do you want to change width/height? ImageView by default preserves aspect ratio of its image...

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, "Image views just doesn't scale up" what does it mean?

Comment: of course they do, just use layout_width / layout_height = "match_parent", if you specify 200dp then its 200dp, if you use match_parent they fill the available space

Comment: button? what button? i dont see any button in your layout file

Comment: so whats wrong with <LinearLayout><Button match_parent/wrap_content/><ImageView match_parent/match_parent/></LinearLayout> ? its not practical? why?

Answer (score 3):

you should use percent for width and height of your image like below

```
        android1:layout_width="0dip"
        android1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="0.4885"
```

Answer (score 1):

use `layout-weight` attribute for the elements.
Suppose inside a `layout`, there are 2 `TextView` elements. 
Setting `layout-weight="1"` for the first and `layout-weight="2"` for the second will divide the total available space to the 2 `TextView` elements in the ratio of `1:2` regardless of the screen size. So, instead of using `dp` values for dimensions, use `layout-weight` attribute to indicate how much space you want your elements to cover.

Comment: So `android:scaleType` isn't necessary in this case, right?

Comment: No. If you use layout-weight, scaleType is not necessary. Infact personally I think, manipulating weight is the best practice when it comes to scalability. You can achieve most things by manipulating the ratio of weight of each item in your layout.